# React Native use an Image as a layer

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I want to use an absolute image as a layer above the rest of my page but when the page opens, I get a flashy effect on Android but not on iOS. For reference, the background is colored and the foreground is a white layer.

Here is how I implemented it.

*View of my mask*

```
const MaskView = styled.View`
  height: ${hp('33%')};
  width: ${wp('100%')};
  position: absolute;
  top: ${hp('9%')};
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
`
```

*Displayed on top of a* https://github.com/heineiuo/react-native-animated-linear-gradient

Here is how the display looks like on Android upon opening the page.

[image: GIF explaining the problem]

Thanks for help!